# INSERT INTO SELECT with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that takes all data from database A and inserts it into database B. It is working correctly, however I created a new column in database B called "actual_date" and I would like that, when inserting the data in database B, also insert the current date when these values ​​were entered in database B.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO databaseB(col1, col2, actual_date) SELECT databaseA.col1, databaseA.col2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM databaseA
```

Obviously the above query is wrong, but it would be something like this, because in database A, there is no column with the current date.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is DatabaseA,  MS-Access or SQL Server or something else?

Comment: Maybe just use `Date()` or `Now()`.

Comment: SYSDATE in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Date()*:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    databaseB (col1, col2, actual_date) 
SELECT 
    databaseA.col1, databaseA.col2, Date() 
FROM 
    databaseA
```